# A Connect Wall to Stymie You

Tags: knowledge, connect-wall

Divide the words into four equal groups to discover what unites the groups.
Prefer no incomplete answers.

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Always | Arachnids | Australia | Britain |
| Lakes | Lazy | Front | Hairbands |
| Hallelujah | Depression | Sea | Spaghetti |
| Handrails | Omelet | Harridans | Carefree |

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The four connected groups are:

> **Group 1: GREAT ___**
>  [Great BRITAIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Britain), [Great LAKES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Lakes), [Great DEPRESSION](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Depression), [Great SEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediterranean_Sea).
>
>  **Group 2: Anagrams of HADRIANS, plus a letter**
>  HANDRAI(L)S, ARA(C)HNIDS, HAR(R)IDANS, HAIR(B)ANDS.
>
>  **Group 3: Can be preceded or followed by WESTERN**
>  [Western AUSTRALIA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Australia), [Western FRONT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Front_(World_War_I)), [SPAGHETTI Western](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_Western), [Western OMELET](https://foodnetwork.co.uk/recipes/western-omelette).
>
>  **Group 4: One-word songs/musicals [written/composed by Irving BERLIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_songs_written_by_Irving_Berlin)**
>  [ALWAYS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Always_(Irving_Berlin_song)), [CAREFREE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carefree_(film)), [HALLELUJAH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hallelujah_(film)), [LAZY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_(Irving_Berlin_song)).

As for the hidden connection between these four groups in this connecting wall...

> ...it's **WALL**!
>
>  [**GREAT** Wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Wall_of_China), [**HADRIAN'S** Wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadrian%27s_Wall), [**WESTERN** Wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Wall), [**BERLIN** Wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin_Wall).

A note on my solve path:

> I have written the groups out in roughly the order I solved the puzzle. The first three 'GREAT' connections came easily to me, and I quickly spotted that the four "HADRIANS+" anagrams looked likely to be anagram-related, though I could not yet spot the significance of the shared letters. Next spotting the four 'WESTERN' connections, I reasoned that the likeliest fourth 'GREAT' member was 'SEA' (a Biblical connection).
>
>  I then spent a fair while musing over the final group, spotting no obvious connection between the remaining four words, until a moment of inspiration when I suddenly noticed that the letters of "HADRIAN'S" were those shared by the almost-anagram group, and clocked the link with 'GREAT' and 'WESTERN'. By considering what fourth famous wall the OP may have included in the puzzle I tried to link the four words with BERLIN, and a short Google search unearthed the links with songs and musicals by Irving Berlin, and everything fell into place!

Comment: This can't be right; it misses the obvious grouping, "Things you chew": omelet, spaghetti, carefree (sugarless gum), arachnids (you know - in your sleep)

Comment: @Rubio Don't forget hairbands... ;-)